# Mozilla Firefox is not displaying the css correctly, although -moz- was added

Tags: html, css, firefox

`display: inline-block;` has been added to the code and to insure that IE and Firefox display it correctly as well `-moz-inline-stack;` and `*display: inline;` were added too.

Although these steps were taken firefox is not willing to display the element correctly.

This is the intended display:

[image: How the element looks like correctly]

This is how firefox is displaying it:

[image: How firefox is displaying it]

```css
  
#currencies {
  display: -moz-inline-stack;
  display: inline-block;
  zoom: 1;
  *display: inline;
  color: black;
  font-size: 0; /* to eliminate space between buttons */
  line-height: 1.5;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#currencies span {
  display: -moz-inline-stack;
  display: inline-block;
  zoom: 1;
  *display: inline;
  padding: 1.5px 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: none #F6F6F6;
  font-size: 12px;
  background-color: transparent;
  font: Montserrat;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  vertical-align: 2px;
}

#currencies .left {
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 4px;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  border-right: none;
}

#currencies .right {
  -moz-vertical-alignment: top;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 4px;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
  border-left: none;
}

#currencies .selected {
  font-weight: normal;
  color: white;
  background: black;
  zoom: 1;
}
```

```html
<span id="currencies">
  <span data-currency="USD" class="selected left">USD</span>
  <span data-currency="EUR" class="middle">EUR</span>
  <span data-currency="CHF" class="right">CHF</span>
</span>
```

Does anyone know a solution for this?

Comment: Your snippet works fine for me in Firefox, so it might be something else in the code that you haven't shown?

Comment: I am also seeing the correct display in Firefox.   It's worth noting that most of your -moz and -webkit rules are unnecessary; the standard `border-radius` rules have been fully supported in both for years, for example.   Firefox also supports `inline-block`, and due to the css order that rule is going to end up overriding the (afaik obsolete) `-moz-inline-stack` rule anyway.  You might consider going through and removing those no-longer-necessary vendor-specific rules (or better yet remove *all* of them, and use css autoprefixer to fill in any that are actually still necessary at build time)

Comment: Hi FluffyKitten, Hi Daniel, thank you both for your replies. The weird thing is that it indeed does display it incorrectly on my firefox and the one of my friend. And thanks daniel, I'll remove the border-radius specific tags, as they are really no longer needed (it's an old code).

Answer (score 0):

put the `-moz-inline-stack` below not above the other:

```
display: inline-block;
display: -moz-inline-stack;
```

on general browsers `display: inline-block;` will work by default and `display: -moz-inline-stack;` will not as they do not recognize this. Though in firefox it will.

Remember: the style that comes last is always applied.

ALSO: I do not understand why use `-moz-inline-stack` as `display: inline-block` works for everybody.

hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to masterpreenz I got on the right "way" I added the -moz- related code below the other code, but it was still not displaying correctly. I had to change the `-moz-inline-stack` to `moz-inline-box` and it worked.

I actually don't understand why in my case firefox did not display `display: inline-block;` correctly, but hey if `-moz-inline-box;` does the job, I'm fine with it.